404 Error on POST Request to /api/read-excel - Endpoint Not Found

I’m working on a project that uses Flask as the backend and Vue.js as the frontend. The goal is to let users upload an Excel file, process it on the backend, and display the results in the frontend. However, I keep running into a 404 NOT FOUND error when I try to send the file via a POST request to the backend endpoint http://localhost:5000/api/read-excel.
I’ve spent a lot of time debugging this but haven’t figured out what’s wrong yet. 

Frontend Code (Vue.js):
Here’s the relevant part of my frontend code from DisasterCodeReader.vue:
<template>
  <div class="disaster-reader">
    <a-upload
      :customRequest="handleExcelUpload"
      :showUploadList="false"
      accept=".xlsx,.xls"
    >
      <a-button :loading="excelLoading">
        <template #icon><upload-outlined /></template>
        Select Excel File
      </a-button>
    </a-upload>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import axios from 'axios';

const handleExcelUpload = async ({ file }) => {
  try {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/read-excel', formData, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    });

    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Upload error:', error);
  }
};
</script>


Backend Code (Flask):
Here’s the backend code in api.py that handles the file upload:
@bp.route('read-excel', methods=['POST'])
def upload_excel_disaster():
    try:
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': 'No file uploaded'}), 400

        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': 'No file selected'}), 400

        if not file.filename.endswith(('.xls', '.xlsx')):
            return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid file type'}), 400

        upload_folder = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'uploads')
        os.makedirs(upload_folder, exist_ok=True)
        filepath = os.path.join(upload_folder, file.filename)
        file.save(filepath)

        import pandas as pd
        try:
            df = pd.read_excel(filepath)
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': f'Failed to parse Excel: {str(e)}'}), 400

        required_columns = ['Disaster Code', 'Description']
        if not all(col in df.columns for col in required_columns):
            return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': f'Missing required columns: {required_columns}'}), 400

        parsed_data = []
        for _, row in df.iterrows():
            disaster_code = str(row['Disaster Code']).strip()
            description = str(row['Description']).strip()

            parsed_data.append({'disaster_code': disaster_code, 'description': description})

        os.remove(filepath)

        return jsonify({'success': True, 'data': parsed_data})
    except Exception as e:
        current_app.logger.error(f'Error processing file: {str(e)}')
        return jsonify({'success': False, 'message': str(e)}), 500


CORS Configuration:
Here’s how I configured CORS in __init__.py to allow the frontend to access the backend:
CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": ["http://localhost:5173"]}})


Backend Initialization (__init__.py):
Here’s how I initialize my Flask app and register the blueprint:
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": ["http://localhost:5173"]}})

    from .routes.api import bp as api_bp
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')

    return app


Registered Routes:
I used print(app.url_map) to check all the routes in the backend, and the api/read-excel route is listed:
/static/<path:filename>
/api/parse-code
/api/disasters
/api/disasters/<int:record_id>
/api/disasters/batch
/api/read-media
/api/read-excel
/api/uploads/<path:filename>
/api/auth/register
/api/auth/login
/api/health


Issue:
Whenever I try to upload the Excel file, I see the following error in the browser console:
POST http://localhost:5000/api/read-excel 404 (NOT FOUND)

I also tried testing the same endpoint in Postman, but I get a 404 error there as well.
Browser Result Image
Postman Interface Test Failure Image
Additionally, testing the same endpoint in Postman also results in a 404 error.
What I’ve Tried So Far:

Verified that the backend server is running on localhost:5000.
Checked the URL and route to ensure correctness.
Confirmed that CORS is properly configured.
Ensured that the uploaded file is in the correct format (.xls or .xlsx).


What I Need Help With:
I feel like I’ve checked everything, but I must be missing something! Has anyone faced a similar issue or noticed something I’m doing wrong? Any help would mean a lot! 
Thank you so much in advance! 

You're posting to the /api/read-excel url, but the code only defines the /read-excel url.

Your post contains several indicators that ChatGPT or another LLM was used to generate it. For a variety of reasons, the use of such generative AI tools is strictly disallowed on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to remove and replace content that was generated using these tools.

@ John Gordon
Thank you for your answer sincerely I confirm that the backend registers /read-excel as /api/read-excel with the following code:
app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix=‘/api’)  

The front-end request path is http://localhost:5000/api/read-excel, which should theoretically be correct.
Confirm in debugging:

the service is running at localhost:5000.
/api/read-excel is shown in app.url_map. 3.
CORS is configured for cross-domain access.

But still returning 404 error, thanks for further suggestions!

@esqew   Thanks for the heads up! The content of my question was summarised from my own code and debugging experience, but may have come across as too formal or generated-like in its presentation. I've re-edited it to make sure it's clear and concise, and more in line with the community's communication style. Can I re-review it? Thank you for your understanding!
